# Replace Specific values to SQL Rows and Randomly Distribute them

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, window-functions

```
|Value|
|7.5  |
|9    |
|15.5  |
|12.5 |
|6.5  |
|9    |
```

The Table has lots of numerical values. I want to change all the rows that have 9 to 8.5 and 10.5. If there are 8 values of 9, then 8.5 and 10.5 should be inserted equally and randomly

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, postgresql, oracle...?

Comment: What if there are 7 values of 9? I assume you are going for an equal distribution of your two values of the population of records where `value = 9`, but which output value wins the larger number of records where the count of records where `value=9` is odd? Or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not matter. Just don't want Too many values of one of the 8.5 and 10.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use window functions:

```
select
    value,
    case rn % 2
        when 0 then 8.5
        when 1 then 10.5
        else value
    end new_value
from (
    select 
        value,
        case when value = 8 
            then row_number() over(partition by value order by rand()) 
        end rn
    from mytable
) t
```

The inner query randomy ranks records that have value `8` - note that the `order by rand()` syntax is not consistent across databases (eg it is supported by MySQL, while SQLServer wants `order by newid()`).

The outer query assigns new values: even ranks get value `8.5`, and uneven ranks get `10.5`.

The subquery is actually just there to shorten the syntax in the outer query, but is not strictly necessary:

```
select
    value,
    case 
        when value = 8 and row_number() over(partition by value order by rand()) % 2 = 0 
            then 8.5
        when value = 8 
            then 10.5
        else value
    end new_value
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks a ton ! We need to also add an ```else value``` statement to copy the other values we want into the main table.